# Bad request 400 JSON parse error

Tags: angular, spring-boot

In front end side

```
  this.reservationService.createReservation(this.reservation).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

this.reservation is ReservationDto type

```
export class ReservationDto {
    email: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    phoneNumber: string;
    reservationDate: string;
    id_seance: number;
    user_id: number;
}
```

In server side

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createEvent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Reservation createReservation(@RequestBody ReservationDTO reservationDTO) {
    return reservationService.createReservation(reservationDTO);
}
```

When i do request i have error

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'function': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException:
```

Request Payload looks like

```
function ReservationDto() {
}
```

Why Payload have form function and 
how the body should look properly?

Comment: It looks like somewhere in your code you have `this.reservation = ReservationDto` or `reservation = ReservationDto`. Maybe a typo and it should be `reservation: ReservationDto`.

Comment: @abetteroliver I have declared reservation: ReservationDto; And i only this.reservation = new Reservation() in code i don't have syntax this.reservation = ReservationDto or reservation = ReservationDto

Comment: @abetteroliver has a possible idea of what's wrong, but it's just a guess. could you post your `createReservation` code ?

Comment: @abetteroliver yes i find error in createReservation i pass as parameter type instead field i pass ReservationDto should reservationDT0, thanks now i have error 500, must cast String to java.Locale.Time, thanks for attention